# NaCl helper process running without a sandbox error using Chrome through Selenium in Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, sandbox

I am facing the following error using Chrome through Selenium in Linux:

```
ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.
ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

Do you have solution for the below error?

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. See [ask].

Comment: What information do u want ? Actually I am doing selenium code build in Jenkins.

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

...implies that the *setuid* of the *sandbox* in your system is not configured, hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be, if you want to run Chrome and only use the namespace sandbox, you can set the flag:

```
--disable-setuid-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the setuid sandbox (Linux only). But if you do so on a host without appropriate kernel support for the namespace sandbox, Chrome will not spin up. As an alternative you can also use the flag:

```
--no-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed.

Example:

```
chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']
},
```

Comment: This didn't seem to have an affect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Jupyterlab and reinstalled it using `sudo -H pip3 install jupyterlab`
On restarting it, I no longer got the message NaCl helper running without sandbox.