# sandbox in ubuntu kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, docker-in-docker

I created a vs code application and it works with docker on a new computer. Just after I created deployment and exposed app on kubernetes this error occurred:

```
 [0622/134831.833081:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
 Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

How can I fix this error?

---

Aug 2 2020:

I created container with privilege in ubuntu terminal:

```
 docker run -ti --privileged -p 2020:80 --name webt2_web webt2
```

and then exposed the container:

```
 kubectl expose deployment webt2-node --name=webt2-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --type=NodePort
```

And the error I got when I start the service is still the same. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need to enable privileged mode for this container. Official documentation in this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#privileged)

Or you can disable sandbox following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544974/nacl-helper-process-running-without-a-sandbox-error-using-chrome-through-seleniu)

Comment: Please add the required information to your answer instead of them just being accessible elsewhere.

Comment: In terms of disabling sandbox, how do I use the commands? I typed them in terminal and it didn't work.

Comment: how do I enable privilege mode for the container? Are there any commands I can use in ubuntu?